# matplotlib.pyplot.axvline Label did not appear when use axvline function

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm writing a function to plot histogram using `matplotlib`
I am trying to add vertical line in `mean, mean+2*sd, and mean-2*sd`. The lines appears on the plot but the label I'm giving to them does not, any idea how to fix that?

Also I am trying to put this text `Mean = "for example x"` But I am using hard coded coordination
`plt.text(400, 0.015, "Mean = {}".format(round(mean, 3)))` How can I use programmatic way to infer the values for the coordinate? 
same in thin line:

`plt.axis([min(data), max(data), 0, 0.02])` Can I get min and max Y values in a more efficient way instead of hard coding them?

```
def hist(location, data, mean, std, n_bins=20, x_label="", y_label="",
                  title=""):
    samples = sorted(data)
    x = np.linspace(min(samples), max(samples), 12)
    y_pdf = stats.norm.pdf(x, mean, std)
    y_skew_pdf = stats.skewnorm.pdf(x, *stats.skewnorm.fit(samples))
    l1, = plt.plot(x, y_pdf, label='PDF')
    l2, = plt.plot(x, y_skew_pdf, label='SKEW PDF')
    # Compute histogram of Samples
    n, bins, patches = plt.hist(samples, n_bins, density=True, facecolor='g', edgecolor='red', alpha=0.75)
    plt.axvline(label='Mean', x=mean, linestyle=':', color='red')
    plt.axvline(label='Mean-2*SD', x=round(mean-2*std, 3), linestyle='dashed')
    plt.axvline(label='Mean+2SD', x=round(mean+2*std, 3), linestyle='dashed')
    plt.xlabel(x_label)
    plt.ylabel(y_label)
    plt.title(title)
    # The first plt.text arguments are coordinates x,y of the plot
    plt.text(400, 0.015, "Mean = {}".format(round(mean, 3)))
    plt.legend((l1, l2), (l1.get_label(), l2.get_label()), loc='upper right')
    plt.axis([min(data), max(data), 0, 0.02])
    plt.savefig(location)
```

Answer (score 0):

It may work to shorten your `plt.legend(...` line to simply:

```
plt.legend(loc='upper right');
```

Which works for me.  I think legend knows where to find the labels you specify in the individual calls.  Being explicit to legend may have caused it not to look up the rest.

Also, the plot function should automatically size to the min/max of your data, which has been my experience.